# How to adapt modal pop up to work inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

How can i adapt the below to action multiple times on the same page while using the same class for each? I want to action this within a loop so they can't have different ids or data-values.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="close">&times;</span>
<p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: So you want one button to open multiple modals, or multiple buttons to open the same modal? Or multiple buttons to open their respective modal?

Comment: multiple buttons to open their respective modals! Essentially i want to change GetElemendByID to GetElementByClassName but it doesn't work when i swap them!